# Silverlight ComboBox Returns Null on second run

Tags: silverlight-5.0, cascade, datagridcomboboxcolumn, dataform

I have a 3 cascading combo boxes: `cb1`, `cb2`, `cb3`.
`cb3` values depend on `cb2` and `cb2` values depend on `cb1` value.

These comboboxes are located inside a DataForm.EditTemplate

The first time I edit an item, everything get's populated.

The second time I edit another item, 
`cb1`, gets populated while
`cb2` & `cb`3 values disappear.

When I debug my code,

this is the codebehind snippet.

```
 var cboC2 = (ComboBox)ProductRequestForm.FindNameInContent("cb2");
 var cboC3 = (ComboBox)ProductRequestForm.FindNameInContent("cb3");
```

returns null.

But when I run again 
no error occurs.

Heres my xaml code.

```
<dataform:DataField  LabelPosition="Top" Label="Status" IsRequired="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                                                    <ComboBox x:Name="cb2"
                                                          SelectedItem="{Binding ProductRequestStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                          DisplayMemberPath="ProductRequestStatusDescription" SelectionChanged="cb2_SelectionChanged" />
                                                </dataform:DataField>

<dataform:DataField  LabelPosition="Top" Label="Severity" IsRequired="True" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
                                                <ComboBox x:Name="cb3" 
                                                          SelectedItem="{Binding ProductRequestSeverity, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                          DisplayMemberPath="ProductRequestSeverityDescription" />
                                            </dataform:DataField>
```

These are triggered by an event `SelectionChanged`.

Please help.

Thank you.